# The [white] tag used for color, but it is actually a framework for UIA on Windows

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The tag [white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/white) is used quite frequently when the user meant white space. It would be good if we could rename that tag to `white-framework` so that fewer questions need to be modified.

[TestStack](https://github.com/TestStack) is the organisation on GitHub that [White](https://github.com/TestStack/White) belongs to which is why I suggest appending that to the tag name. You can look at my reputation gain to get a feel for how many questions have the white tag used incorrectly. Every once in a while I go through the *white* tag and clean it up so that the UIA tag has less clutter when I search for it, but I really shouldn't be getting rep for something that can probably be solved by adding more clarity to the tag's name.

Comment: The annoying trend of naming software projects common nouns bites us again.

Comment: I'd just call it `white-framework`. There's plenty of precedent: [tag:ionic-framework], [tag:phaser-framework], [tag:simple-framework]. These things don't have 'framework' in their official names but the tags use it to make it less ambiguous.

Comment: @qwr I should name my next trending software project `framework`

Comment: @Ray we have a nuget package at my work called Framework, it makes discussions annoying to say the least

Comment: @Ray and make it actually a library, not a framework.

Comment: Also frustrating since a [tag:whitespace] tag exists.

Comment: @qwr Yeah, it makes it annoying to use those because it's hard to Google for problems. I run into that all the time with Orange.

Comment: @Ray I hate you and I love you.

Comment: @Ray: Or *Software Project*

Comment: What *is* [UIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UIA) (in this context)? [Microsoft UI Automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation)? (Another example, BTW)

Comment: @PeterMortensen The UIA in the title is Microsoft UI Automation. The UIA I refer to in the body is the generic concept of UIA. I dont believe there are tags that distinguish between Microsoft UI Automation and UIA as a generic concept unfortunately.

Comment: Perhaps the Microsoft UI Automation tag could be renamed to `microsoft-uia`? Like [`microsoft-word`](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word). There are probably precedents (other meta question about such renaming).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I dont think it would be a good idea to rename uia since it contains all sorts of different types of uia at the moment. I think the new tag would be a good idea then there would need to be a cleanup to add the new tag to all issues about microsoft-uia. Side note it is very annoying that microsoft named their framework uia, makes google searching for it very painful.